# set-register register-separator "\n\n")

Tags: characters, registers

Upon reading [GNU Emacs Manual #rectangle register](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Rectangle-Registers)

> When you are collecting text using append-to-register and prepend-to-register, you may want to separate individual collected pieces using a separator. In that case, configure a register-separator and store the separator text in to that register. For example, to get double newlines as text separator during the collection process, you can use the following setting.
>
> ```
>    (setq register-separator ?+)
>    (set-register register-separator "\n\n")
> ```

I assumed that only the first line is enough as

```
(setq register-separator "\n]n")
```

What does `?+` mean? and the extra `(set-register register-separator "\n\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h v register-separator` says this:

> `register-separator` is a variable defined in `register.el`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Register containing the text to put between collected texts, or nil if none.
>
> When collecting text with `C-M-S-delete` (or `M-x prepend-to-register`),
>   contents of this register is added to the beginning (or end, respectively)
>   of the marked text.
>
> You can customize this variable.

A register is a **character** (which is a positive integer).  `?+` is the notation for the character `+` (which in a string would be `"+"`).

The parent node ([Registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Registers.html)) of the manual page you cite tells you what registers are.

The variable's doc says that the variable's value is a **register**, that is, a character.  Your code sets it to a *string* instead.

The manual example code `(set-register register-separator "\n\n")` sets the register that is the value of variable `register-separator` to have the string value `"\n\n"`.